# 960 Grid for fluid layouts

Tags: 960.gs

For the fluid layouts, can i use 960 grid system for developing web applications..?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with your question? It's not terribly clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 960 grid system for web applications. If you want a fluid version you must select the fluid version to download. The default version is based on a fixed width of 960 pixels. See the download page:

http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but is it a good approach to code for web applications using 960 grid system.

Comment: It depends. Do you know how to use grid systems? Do you need to use a grid systems? Are you a proponent or opponent of grid systems? They are a tool, and thus should be used when a job requires them. Unfortunately "web applications" is not specific enough to give a meaningful response.

Comment: I haven't used extensively in any of my web projs. But i like the Grid system as it is good solution where it solves some cross browser compatibility issues. I am about to start coding for my a web application, so i was wondering whether i can develop using 960 or not

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to http://grids.heroku.com/ and download the fluid version instead of the normal version.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the 960.gs layout and think it looks good on any browser/system except mobile, then you should have a mobile version (jQueryMobile, Sencha etc).

Anyhow if you want something a little larger than 960 there is a new grid system that works quite well called 1140

http://cssgrid.net/

Check out their site. I found 1140 easier to use than 960.gs, in fact I wish they supported 960px resolution :)

Hope this helps!